# Flutter Understanding Navigation

Tags: flutter, navigation

I would like to understand `Navigation` in Flutter better. Currently I have a problem with listening to `authentication changes` and think that it might be connected to the way I am navigating through the app.

I have written a `wrapper class` to listen to `authentication changes` and react accordingly. Now here my first question comes in:

**What is the difference between calling a class like so: return class() vs. navigating to it through for example Navigator.push?**

I am assuming that doing the first prevents me from using the `NavigatorObserver` features such as it creating the back button automatically or overriding the didPop method etc.?

And this leads me to my second question:

**Would you recommend using the Navigator whenever possible and reasonable?**

As you can tell I am in the process of getting to know both programming as well as Flutter better so apologies if those questions are pretty basic.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you need to understand how Navigation works in flutter.

Whenever you push to any page through `Navigator.push` it adds pushed page as a stack. For example imagine list of white papers, the first(home) page which you give in material page is the first paper. Now you have only one white paper(page), and when you push to another page, you add another paper(page) on it. [image: stack]

By changing pages according to changes might be solution in some parts but, not everywhere. Because you might have a lot of pages if you work in real or big project. Therefore there is pop functionality, when you exit from a page it pops to the previous one, so by changing classes according to events can't be an optimal solution here.
Changing classes might be useful in main pages with bottom navigation bar.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that I get the concept, but am struggling with the execution. However, this is already very helpful. You saying that changing classes according to events cannot be an optional solution means that something like listening to authchanges and then returning a certain class based on the login status would be bad practice? 
Changing the classes in the bottom navigation bar makes sense because we do not want to add another page on top of the stack but actually switch over to another one?

Comment: First of all I would like to explain how the navigation works, and difference between Navigator.push and changing classes in general. But in some cases it might be helpful to change classes, instead of pushing to another page. For example, listening to login status and changing page accordingly might be an option here. 
With bottom navigation bar, yes it makes sense to change pages instead of pushing. Because generally apps are almost built same for now. Every app I saw has BottomNavigationBar with 4-5 main pages, in that case we don't have another solution rather than changing classes.